# How to display the data in table format which im currently displaying in page via js ?( i already got input from previous page)

Tags: javascript, html

want to display my data in table format in javascript

able to display the data which i recieved from my previous page through query string  in next page through document.write

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
           <head>
            <title> result </title>
            </head>

<body>

    <script>


        function getParams(){
            var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
            var params = new Array();
            if (idx != -1) {
                var pairs = 
             document.URL.substring(idx+1,document.URL.length).split('&');
                for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
                    nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
                    params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
                }
            }
            return params;
        }
        params = getParams();
        firstname = unescape(params["firstname"]);
        lastname = unescape(params["lastname"]);
        age = unescape(params["age"]);
        email = unescape(params["email"]);
         mobile = unescape(params["mobile"]);


        document.write(  "firstname = " + firstname + "  <br>" );
        document.write( "lastname = " + lastname + "<br>" );
        document.write( "age = " + age + "<br>"  );
        document.write( "email-id = " + email + "<br>" );
       document.write( "mobile = " + mobile + "<br>");
```

```
</body>
```

display my data inside table

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not really understand your question. You want to create an html `<table>`?

Comment: when i run this code ,i am able to fetch data from my previous page and display it through document.write.but i want to display the data in table format. i have tried different ways but nothing works.just want to know how to insert table

Comment: Create a <table> HTML structure the same way. So instead of name + '<br>', you'll have to create all the <td> rows and such.